# How to load script along with modal (only once!)?

Tags: javascript

I need to load some scripts along with a modal form. This modal serves other purposes too. So, when modal is loaded, I need to detect if it contains the form before running the script. I use theses lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        // Init prestation type modal form
        if (document.getElementById("prestaTypeForm")) {
            initPrestationTypeModalForm()
        }
    })
})
```

Unfortunately, the script is loaded each time I open a modal, so the first time it works fine, but the second time, eventListener are added a second time, and third time, three times... it means that when I trigger an action, it is triggered as many times as I have open a modal.

As I said, the modal serves other purpose, so if I run the script once on a different modal, with no form, I can't add listener to non existing node.

Is it a way to prevent this?

Comment: You can't "prevent" this since this is how JS works. What you can do is to adapt your logic and only apply the event listeners once. Have a global variable that is set to true once the listeners are applied for example. Or before you add event listeners, clear other listeners. I think there are multiple solutions to your problem.

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) by binding an ancestor of the form to the event like `document`.

Comment: Since it's a Bootstrap event, it might have to be handled differently. Can't say for sure unless you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used to solve this issue is quite simple. As suggested @cloned, the use of a global variable as flag is the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var initFormDone

    $('#form-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        // Init prestation type modal form
        if (document.getElementById("prestaTypeForm") && (!initFormDone)) {
            initPrestationTypeModalForm()
            initFormDone = true
        }
    })
})
```